# Can we expand $a^b$ to where both are elements of a group? Deriving exponentiation from multiplication group

Tags: group-theory

For some group $(G,\cdot)$ my professor defined $a^n$ where $a \in G$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to be $a^n=a \cdot a \cdot a ...a$ where there are $n$ copies of $a$ (if $n$ is a negative, it's $n$ copies of the inverse and if $n=0$ then the result is the identity element). I was wondering if there was some other definition out there of exponents where the exponent was also from the group.

So is there a definition for $a^b$ with $a, b \in G$? The result would hopefully be another element from the group, but how can you have $b$ repetitions if $b$ doesn't actually count anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define $a^b$ as whatever you want it to be, of course, but in order for it to be considered meaningful, it must be similar to "exponentiation" in some (precisely defined) way. There are different options for this.

You may wish this exponentiation to follow one or more of the usual "laws of exponents". For example, $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$. Since there is no *second* operation $+$, we cannot meaningfully write $(a^b)(a^c) = a^{b+c}$ [unless we define some new operation].

One (very commonly used) definition that satisfies the first property is *conjugation*: For $a, b \in G$, define $a^b = b^{-1}ab$. Then $(a^b)^c = c^{-1}(a^b)c = c^{-1}b^{-1}abc = (bc)^{-1}a(bc) = a^{bc}$ [$\ne a^{cb}$, in general].

This can be generalized. For any fixed [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism/) $\varphi\colon G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ from the group $G$ to its [automorphism group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism#Automorphism_group/) $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, we can define, for $a, b \in G$, $a^b = \varphi_b(a)$, where $\varphi_b$ denotes the automorphism $\varphi(b)$. But now, we will get $(a^b)^c = a^{cb}$. To avoid this, we could define $a^b = \varphi_b^{-1}(a)$ (though that is messy as a definition). The proof that these definitions work as claimed is left as an exercise to the reader! Note that all of this ties up very nicely with left and right actions.

---

If we wish to have both of the aforementioned properties of exponents, we need two operations, so consider a ring $(R, +, \times)$. Let $G$ be the additive group of the ring, written multiplicatively as $(G, \cdot)$, where $G = R$, and for $a, b \in G$, $ab = a +_R b$ (the sum of $a$ and $b$ in the ring $R$). We can then define $a^b$ as $a \times_r b$ (the product of $a$ and $b$ in the ring). Now, we have both properties! Note that all operations written in the exponent actually take place in the ring $R$. So, the product (in $G$), of $a^b$ and $a^c$ is $(a^b)(a^c) = (a \times_R b) +_R (a \times_R c) = a \times_R (b + c) = a^{b+c}$, where the $+$ in the exponent is addition in the ring. Also, $(a^b)^c = (a \times_R b) \times_R C = a \times_R (b \times_R c) = a^{b \times c}$, where the $\times$ in the exponent is multiplication in the ring. If $b$ is a unit of the ring, it has a multiplicative inverse $b^{-1}$, so we can even find the "$b$-th root of $a$"!

---

*Needs some correction:*

> Now, maybe we wish for a different definition — one that "agrees" with the "integer exponent" $a^n$ already defined. But how can the two agree if the exponents are elements of two different sets (the integers vs. the group elements)? Let $M$ be a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid/) that contains (a copy of) $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_n$ as a subgroup (respectively as the [exponent of $G$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group/) is infinity or a finite number $n$). In other words, there is a monoid homomorphism from the monoid $(\mathbb Z, +)$ of (additive) integers into $M$, and the homomorphic image is the subgroup mentioned in the previous statement. Further, suppose this monoid $M$ [acts on $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action/) in such a way that for every (image of the) integer $m \in M$, the action of $m$ on $G$ is defined by $a \mapsto a^m$. Now, we can define a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G \to M$, from the *monoid* $G$ (every group is a monoid) into $M$, and as before, define $a^b = \varphi_b(a)$. If this homomorphism satisfies the property that $a^b = a^m$ whenever $\varphi(b) = m$ is an element of the submonoid $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_n$ of $M$, we can say that our definition of exponentiation *agrees with* integer exponentiation.

Comment: To fix your last comment, just define it as $bab^{-1}$ instead.

Comment: Indeed, if you use that definition, we get $(a^b)^c = a^{cb} \ne a^{bc}$ (intuitively less appealing). I've seen a "left exponentiation" notation used for that sometimes: ${}^b a = bab^{-1}$.

Comment: Woops, I actually read your comment wrong (too little coffee today yet). Indeed the definition you give here is the one with the nicest properties for this purpose.

Comment: Another way to formulate this is in terms of having another group $H$ act on the group $G$, for which this is a special case (and the usual exponentiation also being a special case).

Comment: What if we use a ring like $(R,+, \cdot )$? So that $(a^b)(a^c)=a^{b+c}$ can have some meaning? In this case, the exponential notation would still stem from the multiplication part of the ring

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The usual exponentiation cannot be a special case, can it? It cannot be a group action of $(\mathbb Z, +)$ [or $(\mathbb Z_n, +_n)$] on $G$, because not all power maps are proper permutations of the set $G$. But it can be a *monoid action* of $\mathbb Z$ on $G$. I just finished updating my answer with something like this. Now I'm thinking of further extending it from a monoid to a ring. For an Abelian group, the endomorphism group seems the natural choice.

Comment: Ahh, true, it is not an action of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @M.Vinay I accepted your answer; it was very helpful. I was a little unsatisfied by the ring portion though. I was hoping for the same kind of agreement you showed so nicely with the groups. Maybe naively, I pictured a kind of super ring, like $(R, +, \cdot , \wedge )$ where we add a third operation that extends the first two in a way that generalized exponentiation in the integers

Comment: @Cordello There should be severe limitation to such a definition (a new exponentiation operation on a ring) that agrees with repeated multiplication. Consider the usual ring (field) of rational numbers, $\mathbb Q$. The natural definition of exponentiation of elements of $\mathbb Q$ should be the familiar exponentiation of numbers, which is an extension of integer exponentiation. But there is no $2^{1/2}$ in the ring, nor a $(-1)^{1/2}$. Also, if we take a ring that is not a field (or at least a division ring), we will not even have $a^{-1}$ for some element $a$.

Comment: So, defining such an exponentiation in a ring would require us to extend the ring to a field first, and then further extend the field to make it closed under exponentiation. This would not even be the usual algebraic closure, because now our exponents are field elements.